# Getting content of a div (including child tags) with DOM

Tags: php, dom, xpath

i am using DOM to get content of div tag but inner html part is not shown.
Function is:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile("$url");
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divTag = $xpath->query('//div[@id="post"]');
foreach ($divTag as $val) {
echo $val->getAttribute('title') . ' - ' . $val->nodeValue . "<br />\n";
}
```

if source of page is (just for Div)

```
<div id="post">Some text <img src="..." /> <table>some codes</table></div>
```

then function returns just

```
"Some text "
```

but i want to get all HTML elements too, like that:

```
Some text <img src="..." /> <table>some codes</table>
```

Is there any way to do it? Thanks right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for the DOMDocument version of `innerHTML` in the browser DOM, the nearest is `saveXML`.

```
echo $dom->saveXML(val).'<br />\n';
```

(Remember to htmlspecialchars if you want that to actually appear as text.)

This gives you the `outerHTML` though. If you really need the `innerHTML`, you'd have to loop through each of the element's child nodes and pass them to `saveXML`, then implode them.

And it's XML serialisation only: there is no corresponding HTML version. `saveHTML` does exist but can only save the whole document at once, sadly. If it matters that you get legacy-HTML, you might be able to get away with it by passing in the `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` option to ensure that annoying empty tags like `<script src="..."></script>` don't break the browser.

Comment: thank you, you all right.. Solution is: $dom = new DOMDocument(); libxml_use_internal_errors(true); @$dom->loadHTMLFile("$url"); libxml_use_internal_errors(false); $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom); $divTag = $xpath->evaluate("//div[@id=post]"); $divcontent = $divTag->item(0); echo $dom->saveXML($divcontent); and it works perfectly...

Comment: Since 5.3.6, saveHTML supports an element parameter just like ::saveXML.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the '//' from your Xpath Query...

this tells the XPath parser then to also get all child nodes... which your HTML tags are...

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp

EDIT:

Also check XPath Axes: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: `//` tells XPath to get all nodes, no matter where in the tree. So `//div[@id="post"]` gets all div nodes with an id=post. The fact that you also get the children of the div nodes is incidental.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what bobince said, but i'm adding that you can use output buffering to get the contents if you do this in the php without displaying it in the html.

```
$divTag = $xpath->query('//div[@id="post"]');
ob_start();
foreach ($divTag as $val) {
   echo $dom->saveXML($val);
}
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: What am I missing? Why not `$content='';` and `$content .= $dom->saveXML($val);`? OB can't be faster.

Comment: Yeah i don't know what i was thinking... i actually came to the same conclusion earlier today when i looked at the code i wrote yesterday... is there some way i can delete this post?

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't. Better answers will get more votes, which is all the indication needed for the OP (and others).