# preg match not reading content between table

Tags: preg-match, preg-match-all, php

```
preg_match_all('|<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="Flight Timetable search results" id="timeTable">(.*?)</table>|', $read, $foo, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($foo);
```

output as just

Array ( )

Where i made mistake

See guys ,

Actually i want to grab the exact details from this [URL](http://www.heathrowairport.com/portal/site/heathrow/template.PAGE/menuitem.a43f3a72926ca3b1b0c52a499328c1a0/?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=token&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=token&javax.portlet.tpst=bde211e38117ef94303fde9faca12635&javax.portlet.prp_bde211e38117ef94303fde9faca12635_flightRoute=&javax.portlet.prp_bde211e38117ef94303fde9faca12635_flightNumber=9W5048&javax.portlet.prp_bde211e38117ef94303fde9faca12635_flightTerminal=)

i want to pick this details from this URL

08:35   9W5048       TORONTO     EXPECTED 1358      Terminal three

So i tried this snippet , but it throwing Error like

this is my snippet

> $read = file_get_contents("http://www.heathrowairport.com/portal/site/heathrow/template.PAGE/menuitem.a43f3a72926ca3b1b0c52a499328c1a0/?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=token&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=token&javax.portlet.tpst=bde211e38117ef94303fde9faca12635&javax.portlet.prp_bde211e38117ef94303fde9faca12635_flightRoute=&javax.portlet.prp_bde211e38117ef94303fde9faca12635_flightNumber=9W5048&javax.portlet.prp_bde211e38117ef94303fde9faca12635_flightTerminal=");
>   //echo $read;
>     preg_match_all('/(.*?)</table>/si', $read, $foo, PREG_SET_ORDER);
>     $read1 = $foo[0][0];
>     preg_match_all('/(.*?)</tbody>/si', $read1, $foo1, PREG_SET_ORDER);
>     print_r($foo1[0][0]);

I got Error like

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\wamp\www\plugin\read-airport-arraiwals.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in E:\wamp\www\plugin\read-airport-arraiwals.php on line 8
```

Comment: Regex is not a good way to process html. Use a parser instead

Comment: Your question [Fetch Details From XML Tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219030/fetch-details-from-xml-tag) should contain all the information you need to extract the wanted data. Regex aint for HTML.

Comment: Obligatory warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting content of a div (including child tags) with DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791842/getting-content-of-a-div-including-child-tags-with-dom)

Comment: @Bharanikumar Of course it is. It is an XHTML page, which makes it an XML application. But even if it was an HTML page, which is loosely derived from SGML, it would be parseable with DOM or XMLReader, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/timeTable" .*<tbody>(.*?)<\/table>/smU', $read, $foo, PREG_SET_ORDER);
preg_match_all('/<(th|td).*>(.*)<\/(th|td)>/smU', $foo[0][1], $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($result);
```

And you will get the required data. Quick answer because I don't have time to create a single pattern for that, but this one will do the job.

Comment: Is it possible to make array very simple, 
That is values in single dimension array